# Is my question appropriate for Stack Exchange? If so, where should I ask? If not, where else can I ask?

Tags: support, site-recommendation, scope

My question is this: What is it like working in the IT security field and what skills are required?

I was looking for a "career" site but there doesn't seem to be one so I thought instead of the Information Security site. After looking at questions asked there, I didn't think mine would be appropriate.

Also, if my question is unappropriate for Stack Exchange, is there a place I could ask it?

I'm not even sure Meta is the right place for this question but I couldn't find a [whereshouldipost.stackexchange.com](http://whereshouldipost.stackexchange.com).

Comment: You're in the correct place to ask "where should I ask this on SE"... but personal commentary is not what we do on SE... Questions here must generally be concrete and objective... every single person will have a different answer to this question and every single job will have a different list of skills required.

Comment: +1 because I wish every new user acted like you before posting their new question.

Comment: Thanks. I know this question is quite old now but I forgot to thank you guys for your help.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The question is both too broad and opinion based. Everybody who works in the IT security field will have a different experience of that based on what they've encountered in that role.

Such questions are off-topic on Stack Overflow as they don't have a "right" answer. It's possible that other sites such as [Reddit](https://www.reddit.com/r/cscareerquestions) or [Quora](https://www.quora.com/) would entertain this kind of question but you should check them out beforehand.

Comment: A better subreddit would be [r/cscareerquestions](https://www.reddit.com/r/cscareerquestions), though, as always make sure to read the [faq](https://www.reddit.com/r/cscareerquestions/wiki/index), [search](https://www.reddit.com/r/cscareerquestions/search?restrict_sr=on), and any [pinned posts](https://www.reddit.com/r/cscareerquestions/comments/1wumga/please_read_this_before_posting/) before posting. There is also an [/r/ITCareerQuestions](https://www.reddit.com/r/ITCareerQuestions)

Comment: @MichaelT ta, I've fixed the link.